# Open text file in SSIS and store the first line in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

What is the best was I can open a `txt file` in a `SSIS` and store the first line as a variable.

I want to put a list of accounts in the `txt file` and use them in a `SQL task`.

Comment: I believe that [this is the way to go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324149/ssis-how-do-i-load-data-from-text-files-where-the-path-of-files-is-inside-anot). Only difference is you don't have tzo iterate all of the rows, so it should be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the link @Ozren gave you, to create a proper flat file connection e.g `myfile` and variable  e.g.`HeaderLine`. Then create a script task, put HeaderLine var in `read/write variables` and code it with:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader(Dts.Connections["myfile"].ConnectionString);
Dts.Variables["HeaderLine"].Value = file.ReadLine();
file.Close();
```

That's pretty much it, then you can put a standard DataFlow to read filedata from file to DB or resultset.

You'll have the first line in HeaderLine variable, which you can use anywhere you want in the SSIS package.