# Copy data from postgres to sql server with very similar schema

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, postgresql

I have data in postgres that I need to programmatically move to sql server on a scheduled basis. The tables have the all have same schema and the tables are not very relational (no foreign keys), but I think I can just use `WITH NO CHECK` if there are.

I have ADO.Net connectors for both servers, so I think I can just select from the postgres to a `DataTable` and then `INSERT INTO` the SQL SERVER tables. However, I'm a little concerned on performance.

My question is how hard would it be to use the Postgres `COPY` command to export to say CSV, and then use bcp.exe to import the CSV into SQL SERVER. Does this sound like the way to go? I can see this needing to scale to ~750k records being copied per schedule.

Comment: You might also be able to create an SSIS package to do this, which would probably perform much better.  Take a look at https://slalomdotcom.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/connecting-to-a-postgresql-instance-using-sql-server-integration-services/

Comment: How much can you change an SSIS package from use to use programatically? I need to change the search path for each copy (there are many schema's we are selecting from) on postgres.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273751/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-net