# SSIS 2008 Setting Child Package variables from C#/.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ssis

I was researching how to execute a 2008 SSIS package from C#/.NET and found the following helpful article.

[How to execute an SSIS package from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273751/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-net#)

My assumption is that you can set parent package variables from the calling C# program but you cannot explicitly do so for child package variables.  So that any child variables that need to be dynamic have to "trickle down" from the parent.  Is that correct?  I've had no luck researching this so any pointers to articles are very welcome.  I don't mind doing the work at all.

Comment: When you start an ssis package, you can specify the initial value of variables. The Execute Package Task for 2008 does not allow you to specify starting values but if you are launching child processes from .net, there's no reason you can't use the overloaded [Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.dtscontainer.execute.aspx)

Comment: If you are for some reason or another not able to fire off from .net you could always drop those variables into a table and then call them during the execute package task. It's kind of a kludgy workaround but just throwing that out there.

Comment: I find it helpful in SSIS to not think of a parent package "passing" variables to a child package, but instead think of the child package "inheriting" variables from the parent.