# SSIS not running from C# console app with no errors VS2012

Tags: c#, ssis

I have been using Managed DTS runtime assembly in VS2012 to control an SSIS package from a C# windows app for testing. Everything works fine.

I try to copy the code to run from a Console app (for production reasons ) and nothing works the SSIS package runs and executes with succes but nothing actually happens.

I had to reinstall VS2012 to fix another error and I am assuming I have missed something when I have reinstalled  but cant see what it is

The original app still works after reinstalling VS but the new app does not connect to the SSIS package at all.

Can anybody point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are of little value

Comment: Could you share your code?  Is the console application code being run from the same computer as the Windows application that works?  Take a look at the first answer in the following link.  It may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273751/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-net

Answer (score 0):

Apologies guys 
was quite frustrated yesterday and forgot the basic rules of posting questions

I managed very late last night to fix the problem 
I had forgotton to put 
 in the app.config file

It now works fine ... duh (6 hrs wasted)

this is a reminder why we comment code , cause we forget things like this when we copy the code

I appreciate the answers/help
thanks

Comment: It seems it has not posted the " startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" "