# c# - Running multiple SQL scripts

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssms

I know my question seems a bit broad but I'll try to be as specific and brief as possible. So I am currently working on a program in c# about data archiving. Basically, I'll have a button and when I click it, it should generate new tables into my SQL server database.

My issue is the approach on executing the queries. I already have a list of sql script files (written in SSMS) and I would like to execute them(in sequence) in c#. 
Should I hardcode the script into my c# program to create the table? It would look something like this:

```
  private void btnCreateTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string query = "IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST','U') IS NULL ";
    query += "BEGIN ";
    query += "CREATE TABLE[dbo].[AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST]( "; 
    query += "[AuditID] [decimal](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[AuditType] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CardTypeBenefitID] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL, ";

    query += "[EventCode] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CardTypeGroupID] [varchar](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
    query += "[AgeFrom] [int] NULL, ";
    query += "[AgeTo] [int] NULL, ";

    query += "[Gender] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL, ";
    query += "[CreateBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[Status] [char](2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[CancelReason] [varchar](250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[LastChangeBy] [nvarchar](128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[LastChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL, ";
    query += "[RecordVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL ";
    query += ") ON [PRIMARY] ";
    query += "END "; }
```

Or should I execute the script files by using reading the files(calling them) in c# ? I was wondering if it is possible to read them in specific sequence. Also, some SQL statement in the script files are not compatible by reading them in c# such as GO statement for example.

I was thinking of hardcoding in it like the code I just posted above since it can execute the tables generation in the order I want. Problem is imagine if I want to create say,50 tables, then the line of code is going to be really long.

As my idea is to click on the button and then it shall create all the tables in the sql server.

What suggestion would be the best?

EDIT: 
I tried executing sql script files instead and see if it would work. Here is it:

```
private void btnCreateTables_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\88106221\\Documents\\PromotionEvent_Test.sql");
                    string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(con));
                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
   }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}", Environment.NewLine));
                textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}{2}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message, Environment.NewLine));
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} MainPage_Load() exception - {1}", _strThisAppName, ex.Message));

            }
```

Now it says it could not locate my directory for PromotionEvent_Test.sql. I checked the directory and it's correct. What is the cause?

Comment: Suggestion: Use literal string (`@"(IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.AuditCardTypeBenefit_TEST','U') IS NULL) ..."`) to wrap long SQL queries, or put the query into stored procedure/script file and call that instead.

Comment: But I have different sql scripts and each script represents a different table with different data types, constraints,triggers,indexes,etc. Wouldn't your suggestion be concatenating everything into one query?

Comment: If you already have the SQL scripts as files, you might want to simply put them all in a directory and name them 1.sql, 2.sql, ...n.sql. Then you can read them in the order you want.

Comment: @Zohar, that's what I had in mind for now. But can c# read the script files identically as to how SQL server read them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute an SSIS package from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273751/how-to-execute-an-ssis-package-from-net)

Comment: @LordCookie why not? It's a simple text file after all. I've used this technique myself when one of my clients upgraded his SQL Server. They had about 200 tables and about a 1000 stored procedures. I can't remember why but I couldn't simply backup and restore to the new servers, nor could I use SSIS, so the only option I've had was to script the database and run in on the new servers.

Comment: Filder, it's not a duplicate as I have read that thread. It doesn't explain how I would call the script files.

Comment: It's all there. Just follow the links.

Comment: What about Imran's suggested answer below? It seems to run the sql scripts but it's the own method.

Comment: Zohar Because I have seen threads claiming it doesn't recognize certain sql statement in SQL server such as "GO" command so that might be a problem.

Comment: Zohar, I edited my code. See if that's you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Script Files use this C# Method.

```
public void CreateDataBase(string FileNameWithPath)
{
    List<string> cmds = new List<string>();
    if (File.Exists(_pFileNameWithPath))
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(FileNameWithPath);
        string line = "";
        string cmd = "";
        while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Trim().ToUpper() == "GO")
            {
                cmds.Add(cmd);
                cmd = "";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd += line + "\r\n";
            }
        }
        if (cmd.Length > 0)
        {
            cmds.Add(cmd);
            cmd = "";
        }
        tr.Close();
    }
    if (cmds.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString To Master");
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if (command.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < cmds.Count; i++)
                {
                    command.CommandText = cmds[i];
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox(exp.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it

```
CreateDataBase ("C:\1.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\2.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\3.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\4.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\5.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\6.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\7.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\8.SQL");
CreateDataBase ("C:\9.SQL");
```

Comment: I'll give this a try

Comment: I was thinking of putting these into my "btnCreateTables" so it will generate the tables when I click it.  Would it work the same way?

Comment: @LordCookie I'd like to discourage executing this directly in the button_click handler. It will block your UI Thread leaving the App unresponsive.

Comment: But that is the way at least I would like to make my program behave this way.